# Why isn't my ReactJS component dynamically rendering?

Tags: reactjs, foreach, radio-button

I am trying to fetch an array of JSON objects from the server and render the contents of each object dynamically-into a group of radio buttons.

In this example, I've got an array of 28 JSON objects, so I should see 29 radio buttons render (28 + 1 at the bottom of my code sample below) but they aren't rendering.

What am I missing?

```
export default function RadioButtonGroup({insurances, isLoaded}) {
    if (!isLoaded) {
        return (<h5>Loading...</h5>);
    } else return(
        <>
        {
            insurances.forEach((element) =>
                <div id={`radioDiv_${element.id_in_group}`}>
                    <input type="radio" id={`button_${element.id_in_group}`} name="insGroup"/>
                    <label for={`button_${element.id_in_group}`}>{element.insurance_name}</label><br/>
                </div>      
        )}
            <input type="radio" id="notListed" name="insGroup"/>
            <label for="notListed">My insurance is not listed.</label>
        </>
    );
}
```

The fetch works, and I have tested that I am getting an array of JavaScript objects out of the fetch, then passed as a prop to my function component (tested via console.log).

But when I view my component in the browser, the only radio button that appears is "My insurance is not listed", the radio button outside the dynamic radio button group.

Comment: What shows up in the command line if you print the entire insurances.forEach... code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `foreach()` is not returning anything as it just runs the function provided(which has no return method). **I suggest using the `map()` method instead, especially if you have an array of objects(json)**

```
 {insurances.map((element) => (
          <div id={`radioDiv_${element.id_in_group}`}>
            <input
              type="radio"
              id={`button_${element.id_in_group}`}
              name="insGroup"
            />
            <label for={`button_${element.id_in_group}`}>
              {element.insurance_name}
            </label>
            <br />
          </div>
        ))}
```

### If you still have issues:

It is likely your object might have a slightly different object param names, it can be something as small as an accidental capital letter or missing a char etc. So make sure to double check the object being passed in has identical param names to the ones you are trying to extract.

### Example

If you have an object called MyObject and it has a format like this: `{name:string, id:number}`
If I tried `console.log(MyObject.id)` there should be no error but if I accidentally typed: `console.log(MyObject.Id)` then I will always get a null or undefined value because there is no param called 'Id', instead it should be 'id'.

Comment: Huh, I have no clue why this works (I had tried .map() previously and have example code that is identical to what you posted here) but it works. I'm happy. Thanks a billion!

Comment: No problem! Sometimes it can be the smallest difference. One thing that I used to run into is not noticing when i did map(()=>{}) vs map(()=>()), the first will always have an error because map needs a return method so you'd have to add map(()=>{ return <div> example</div>})